# systemd DynamicUser vs User

Tags: systemd, security, users

To run processes without root privileges you can use DynamicUser= or a static user with User= in systemd.
A good explanation for DynamicUser can be found in this blog post: http://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html

Though which one is more secure? What are the exact difference between DynamicUser and User except that DynamicUser uses a dynamic user and User requires a system user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DynamicUser` is more secure because it implies:

- `ProtectSystem=strict`: The entire file system hierarchy is mounted read-only, except for the API file system subtrees `/dev/`, `/proc/` and `/sys/`.
- `ProtectHome=read-only`: The directories `/home/`, `/root`, and `/run/user` are made read-only for processes invoked by this unit.
- `PrivateTmp=yes`: Sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` directories inside it that are not shared by processes outside of the namespace. This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but makes sharing between processes via `/tmp/` or `/var/tmp/` impossible. If this is enabled, all temporary files created by a service in these directories will be removed after the service is stopped.
- `RemoveIPC=yes`: All System V and POSIX IPC objects owned by the user and group the processes of this unit are run as are removed when the unit is stopped

You can mimic these settings by setting them explicitly when using `User=`, getting effectively the same protection.

One way in which `DynamicUser=` is much better is when making instances of a service.  Let's say you have `foo.socket` which uses `Accept=yes`.  In this case, every time someone connects to your socket, a new `foo@%i.service` is spawned.  With `DynamicUser=` each instance has its own namespace and `/tmp` directory which would have been shared if `User=` was used.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from specifying a `User` option even when you set `DynamicUser=true`.

According to the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=) for `User=` (emphasis mine):

> **When used in conjunction with `DynamicUser=` the user/group name
> specified is dynamically allocated at the time the service is started,
> and released at the time the service is stopped** — unless it is already
> allocated statically (see below). If `DynamicUser=` is not used the
> specified user and group must have been created statically in the user
> database no later than the moment the service is started, for example
> using the sysusers.d(5) facility, which is applied at boot or package
> install time. If the user does not exist by then program invocation
> will fail.

There is however a restriction, stated in the `DynamicUser=` part of the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser=):

> ...Note that if `User=` is specified and the static group with the name
> exists, then it is required that the static user with the name already
> exists. Similarly, if `Group=` is specified and the static user with the
> name exists, then it is required that the static group with the name
> already exists.

Basically what that means is that if you specify a custom `User` with the `DynamicUser` option, and a group exists which has the same name as the User, then the user itself must already have been created on the system. The same goes for specifying a custom `Group`.

ex. if you specify `User=docker`, and the `docker` group exists on your system, then the `docker` user must also already exist in order for you to use that name.

The solution to the above restriction is basically to make sure that you do not use a user or group that already exists on the system.

---

**tl;dr**

To answer your question, `DymamicUser=` will indeed improve security, but it's not an issue of whether or not to use `User` or `DynamicUser`. A `DynamicUser` can have an actual `User` associated with it, but this user will **not** be *added* to `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group`.

#### Sources:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html
- https://0pointer.net/blog/dynamic-users-with-systemd.html