# What could cause EROFS error for an openat call of a symlinked path, but only sometimes?

Tags: symlink, nfs, amazon-ec2, system-calls

I'm trying to debug an issue which I see only intermittently, often only once or twice per server and then it goes away. I have an application which attempts to open a lock file using `openat()` with the `O_WRONLY|O_CREAT` flags. Due to the environment configuration, this lock file resides in a directory which must be located on a read-only network share. (Technically this is an AWS EFS share, but it presents as if it were an NFS share)

Because the mount point is read-only, we have placed a symlink at the path where the application expects the lockfile to reside; the symlink target is a nonexistent path under `/tmp` (which is writable)

```
# ls -l /mnt/share/files/.LOCK
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 16 Jan  1  1970 /mnt/share/files/.LOCK -> /tmp/application.LOCK
# ls -l /tmp/application.LOCK 
ls: cannot access /tmp/application.LOCK: No such file or directory
```

Normally, this works perfectly fine. The application opens the *target* of the link, creating the file (under `/tmp`) and all is well. But on occasion, typically the first time a server is provisioned and the application is started, the application is unable to write to this file. The write fails with a `EROFS` (Read-only file system) error.

I have run `strace -s 1024 -y -e trace=%file -f` and caught the error, as well as a subsequent success, with no apparent difference between them:

```
...
[pid 17654] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/share/files/.LOCK", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = -1 EROFS (Read-only file system)
...
[pid 17654] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/share/files/.LOCK", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666) = 112</tmp/application.LOCK>
...
```

Before this test, `/tmp/application.LOCK` did not exist and afterwards, `/tmp/application.LOCK` was a regular file with the text `test\n`

Running an echo through `strace` shows nearly the same syscall and succeeds every time I have tried it:

```
# strace -s 1024 -y -e trace=%file -f bash -c "echo test > /mnt/share/files/.LOCK`
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "echo test > /mnt/share/files/.LOCK"], 0x7ffc3a86df10 /* 22 vars */) = 0
...
access("/usr/bin/bash", R_OK)           = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/mnt/share/files/.LOCK", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3</tmp/application.LOCK >
```

One thing I suspect may be related is that the application is a systemd service, running with `ProtectSystem=full`, `PrivateTmp=yes` and `PrivateDevices=yes`... but this doesn't change, and so I am not sure why sometimes the access would work and sometimes it would fail. (Yes, I checked the private temp directory systemd creates, not just `/tmp`, and when the calls succeeds the file is created under `/tmp/systemd-private-blah/tmp/` as expected)

What could cause a `EROFS` (Read-only file system) error when using `openat()` to write to a symlink, but only occasionally/intermittently?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this happend to me just with at.ftpd daemon.
The systemd.service was set to `DynamicUser=yes` and caused the read-only FS.

See here that DynamicUser implies a couple of modes:
[systemd DynamicUser vs User](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635027/systemd-dynamicuser-vs-user)